# How to combine the two CSS rules with a single selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two CSS rules with different selectors which I want to combine. Both rules have the same CSS properties. The first selector targets `th` elements, and the other selector targets `td` elements:

```
.MyClass th:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+9){
    text-align: right;
}

.MyClass td:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+9){
    text-align: right;
}
```

I suppose it is possible to combine these two rules, but how?

**EDIT**

Okey, I know I put my answer in wrong. My question is a little to simple!

I already was aweare of putting them together with a comma like this:

```
.MyClass th:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+9),
.MyClass td:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+9){
    text-align: right;
}
```

But what I actually wanted to know is how to only do a single selector of `:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+9)`.

Comment: by putting them next to each other seperated by comma?

Comment: Gosh I hate when an answer is so easy, and I keep putting comments.

Comment: Put it as an answer then... ;-)

Comment: It is kind of too late now :D I wont get the credit for it, how rude.

Comment: Or actually contribute to the site and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I know there should be more questions like mine. But it's a pain in the ass to find it. Tried several search queries, but after 15 minutes, it takes in my opinion to much time! I suppose it would be better if I asked this question in the chatbox!

Comment: There is no issue with that. Mark it as duplicated will actually help for future requests about the same thing, and hopefully, nobody will have the same experience as yours when trying to find answer for something already existing on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
.MyClass th:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+9), 
.MyClass td:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+9) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But I hoped for a shorter version! I will change my question.

Comment: @Timo002 don't change, post another....

Answer (score 3):

Use a comma `,` separator, here is a sample

```
.class1, .class2 {
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why a downvote here?